# Sending mail from a contact form. Simple but challenging!

Tags: php, contact-form

I've set up a contact form in the Greet Us page in http://swedsb.com

When I submit the form, it says mail sent successfully. But I'm not getting the mail, checked the spam folder.

I've set a similar form at http://ibsolutions.in. It is working perfectly.

Been breaking my head for the past 4 hours. Here's my contact.php

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "ekalaivan@gmail.com";
    $subject = $_POST['posRegard'];
    $name = $_POST['posName'];
    $email = $_POST['posEmail'];

    if ( preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $posName ) || preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $posEmail ) ) {
    header( 'Location: http://swedsb.com/' );
    }

    $message = $_POST['posText'];
    $body = "$name has sent you a greeting. \n E-Mail: $email\nMessage:\n $message";

    mail($to, $subject, $body);
    header( 'Location: http://swedsb.com/' );
 } 
 else {echo "blarg!";}?>
```

Comment: I urge you to google about mail header injection if you don't want your script to become a spammer's tool.

Comment: Yeah, the `mail()` function is next to impossible to secure, using it on a public facing page allows spammers to use -your- server to send their email, without you ever being the wiser.  I advise looking into `PEAR::mail` instead.

Comment: **DIE! DIE! DIE!** - *after the header...*

Comment: I've modified it using pregmatch(). Hope that will prevent the mail header injection.

Comment: Hey guys thanks a lot for all the help. I caused my own trouble. I had to change the email in two files: contact.php and an xmlHttpRequest.php. But changed in only one. 

Sorry to have wasted your time. 

Feel free to give a thumbs down.

Answer (score 2):

PHP will always say the mail was send...
Checks the path of sendmail in your php.ini file...

Comment: Yep, all "sent successfully" means is it was put in the outgoing queue for sendmail (or equivalent) to process.  You'll need to check the mail daemon on the box to see what happened to it.

Comment: What should I check the file for? 

I'm using a shared server at Dreamhost. Is it still possible to check the path of php.ini? 

Thanks much.

Comment: How do I check the mail daemon?

Comment: Try a phpinfo(), and search for 'mail'

Answer (score 0):

There is no space between

```
<?phpif
```

the script looks good you can check the ini file, or contact to ur server admin if the mail settings are on.

Comment: I've fixed the typo. 

I'm on a shared server and the mail from another website on the same server gets sent perfectly. 

Should I still try contacting the server admin?

Comment: then there should be no problem on ini or other since it works same for all. Sometime it took some time you can check sending mail at other address try yahoo. the script looks ok

Comment: also try adding proper header parameter, reference [php-manual]http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking the mail server logs. Generally speaking you'll find them somewhere like:
/var/log/mail.log.

After locating the log file, run the script and then immediately review the log file and see what happens. Search for the recipient (to address) e-mail to find entry in the log.

Best of luck!

p.s. This script has some serious security problems as-is. Expect spammers will try and trick your code into sending e-mails on their behalf. In particular is important to check any variables which will be used as part of the e-mail headers or content. These values should be sanitized. Look for line feeds, multipart/mixed MIME content boundary markers, and BCC or other headers, and anything else which looks funny. Always send from an explicit e-mail address you provide, do not use the from address the user enters in web form.